# How to Join 2 Varaibles in YAML

Tags: yaml, cypress, azure-yaml-pipelines

How to Join 2 variables in YAML

```
variables:
  - name: Table
    value: 'table'
    
  - name: Tennis
    value: 'tennis'
  - name: Combine
    value: variables.Tennis + ' is '+ variables.Table
```

The expected output is "table is tennis"

I tried concatenating 2 variables or 2 parameters into a variable and it's not working out with + please suggest

Answer (score 0):

```
  - name: commonCommand
    value: ${{ format(' {0} is {1} ', variables.Table, variables.Tennis)}}
```